# Most efficient way to pull specified rows from a 2-d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I have a 2-D numpy array with 100,000+ rows. I need to return a subset of those rows (and I need to perform that operations many 1,000s of times, so efficiency is important).

A mock-up example is like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,5.5],
             [2,4.5],
             [3,9.0],
             [4,8.01]])
b = np.array([2,4])
```

So...I want to return the array from a with rows identified in the first column by b:

```
c=[[2,4.5],
   [4,8.01]]
```

The difference, of course, is that there are many more rows in both a and b, so I'd like to avoid looping. Also, I played with making a dictionary and using np.nonzero but still am a bit stumped.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

**EDIT:** Note that, in this case, b are identifiers rather than indices. Here's a revised example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[102,5.5],
             [204,4.5],
             [343,9.0],
             [40,8.01]])
b = np.array([102,343])
```

And I want to return:

```
c = [[102,5.5],
     [343,9.0]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** Deleted my original answer since it was a misunderstanding of the question. Instead try:

```
ii = np.where((a[:,0] - b.reshape(-1,1)) == 0)[1]
c = a[ii,:]
```

What I'm doing is using broadcasting to subtract each element of `b` from `a`, and then searching for zeros in that array which indicate a match. This should work, but you should be a little careful with comparison of floats, especially if b is not an array of ints.

**EDIT 2** Thanks to Sven's suggestion, you can try this slightly modified version instead:

```
ii = np.where(a[:,0] == b.reshape(-1,1))[1]
c = a[ii,:]
```

It's a bit faster than my original implementation.

**EDIT 3** The fastest solution by far (~10x faster than Sven's second solution for large arrays) is:

```
c = a[np.searchsorted(a[:,0],b),:]
```

Assuming that `a[:,0]` is sorted and all values of `b` appear in `a[:,0]`.

Comment: Right - that's cool, but in my case, I need to match the values. For example, b is like identifiers, not indices. I will edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: `(a - b) == 0` is the same as `a == b`, even when broadcasting is involved.

Comment: @JoshAdel Thanks tons! Luckily, my b array is ints, so I should be OK on the float issue.

Comment: @Josh: What peeves me about both our answers is that the complexity is `O(len(a)*len(b))`, where theoretically `O((len(a)+len(b))*log(len(b)))` would be enough (Sorting `b` and doing a binary search for every element of `a[:,0]`).  Any ideas how to improve this?  Can we use `searchsorted()`?

Comment: @Sven: Good call - `np.searchsorted` is easy to apply to this case and is significantly faster

Comment: @Josh: Nice!  Of course this assumes that `a` is sorted by its first column, and that every item of `b` actually appears in `a[:,0]`, but judging from the OP's examples, these assumptions seem to be valid.

Comment: @Sven and @Josh - Thanks to you both for the constructive discussion! After thinking about this a bit, I tried using sets since my `b` vector is often only missing a few elements relative to the columns in `a`. Nonetheless, @Josh's 3rd suggestion about was about 10x faster than the sets solution. So great that I an move forward now!

Answer (score 4):

A slightly more concise way to do this is

```
c = a[(a[:,0] == b[:,None]).any(0)]
```

The usual caveats for floating point comparisons apply.

**Edit**: If `b` is not too small, the following slightly quirky solution performs better:

```
b.sort()
c = a[b[np.searchsorted(b, a[:, 0]) - len(b)] == a[:,0]]
```

Comment: And props to Sven: I think his method is ~1.6x faster than my solution.

Comment: @Josh: Thanks for timing this! You got my +1 anyway for providing a working answer first. :)

Comment: as shown in Edit 3 of my post, you can use searchsorted directly. It's also worth noting that both of your solutions only extract unique entries in `b`, so if that is important to the OP, than this is also a consideration.